# Queues - "dereferecing pointer to incomplete type"

Tags: c

So, I'm trying to write a few tests. I have a file called listQueue.c (not shown but working) which contains a series of a bunch of function operations on 'queues'. Now my problem lies when I try to write some tests for one of the functions in listQueue.c in a separate file I called testQueue.c.

My listQueue.c:

```
// Creates an empty Queue
Queue createQueue (void){ 
   Queue q = malloc (sizeof (*q));
   assert(q != NULL); 
   q->head = NULL; 
   q->tail = NULL;
   q->size = 0; 
   return q;
}
```

testQueue.c contains:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

   printf("Test 1 - Testing create q\n");
   Queue q = createQueue();
   printf("%d", q->size);
   assert(q->head == NULL);
   assert(q->tail == NULL);
   printf("All tests passed, createQueue works fine.\n");

   return 0;
}
```

The 'header file' Queue.h "

```
  typedef struct queueImp *Queue; 
  //Function Prototypes 
  Queue createQueue(void);
```

Now when I tried to compile it it spits out an error.

"Dereference pointer to an incomplete type." I suspect it's something to do with how I called createQueue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. And yes I have included Queue.h above my main!

Comment: But where is the declaration for struct queueImp ?

Comment: In listQueue.c I have declared it.

Comment: So the `struct` is not visible inside the `main` and the compiler complains, naturally.

Comment: Sorry if what I am about to say is wrong. But I have included Queue.h in testQueue.c. Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: @user3095961 no, you only have a typedef for Queue in there, not how the actual struct look like. When you compile testQueue.c, the compiler has no idea that your Queue has a ->head member - that fact is in the listQueue.c file which the compiler have no idea that exists when you compile testQueue.c

Comment: If the definition of the structure in question is not in the header but only a pointer to it then this is by intention. The reason is to hide the queue's implementation's details. You need to provide functions to access any members of the structure or to perfom operations on it. Those functions go into the *.c to which the header belongs implementing the interface.

Comment: Oh I see. But I compiled it like:

gcc -Wall -Werror -O -o queue testQueue.c listQueue.c

Wouldn't that indicated to the compiler that the structure exists?

Comment: @user3095961 No, the compiler still compiles each .c file as completely separate units. The only way you'd accomplish this is to `#include <listQueue.c>` in your testQueue.c file (which isn't a very good idea)

Answer (score 4):

When you deference `q` in main(), compiler hasn't seen the definition of `struct queueImp` yet. Hence, it errors out as the compiler can't determine the size of the object.

Put the defintion of `struct queueImp` (not sure where you have it at the moment -- I don't see anywhere in your posted code) in `queue.h` and make sure to include it.

Comment: The thing is, we are not allowed to change the queue.h file. So is there a way I can include it in testQueue.c?

Comment: Convention is to put such struct in a header file. If you put it in a C file, you'll be forced to include that C file which is considered as a bad practice. Why you are not allowed to change queue.h? Because that's the struct defintion logically belongs!

Comment: We are not allowed to put it in queue.h purely because when I've finished my testQueue.c and modifying listQueue.c we are suppose to hand it in and it is marked by a 'computer' which checks if the .h file has been altered.

Comment: @BlueMoon: "*Convention is to put such struct in a header file*" not necessarily. Please see my comment on this to the OP.

Comment: @alk If you are talking about *opaque pointer* then the code is still flawed as it should only be defined in `listQueue.c`, thus can't be used ( i.e. de-referenced in main()). I am guessing this is a mistake of OP's understanding of it.

Comment: @user3095961 In that case, put the defintion in `listQueue.c` and do ALL operations (i.e. no de-referencing etc) in that file. Just including the .h file in testQueue.c is enough.

Comment: Wait, when you say put the definition, I assume you mean the struct queueImp. That is already in listQueue.c though.

Comment: @user3095961 The crux of the problem is that you can't de-refernece an incomplete type in `testQueue.c` as the defintion of the struct is not known here ( I believe this is intentional). Whatever you want to do on the queue, do it in the functions defined in `listQueue.c` and just call those functions from main(). The lines `printf("%d", q->size); assert(q->head == NULL); assert(q->tail == NULL);` are your problem. You probably have to define functions in `listQueue.c` like `isEmpty()`, `getQueueSize()` etc instead of directly de-referencing the members from main() to get those info.